# How would I set up a server for my website to hold my PDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, server

I know that I can't put a link on a website to a PDF that's sitting on my computer.  The files have to be either on another website or on my site's server.

My goal is to change the path of the url upon clicking the anchor tag in order to get rid of the hash appended to the url when clicking on a link that's sitting on my computer.

My question is:  How would I go about setting that up?  I'm kind of new at this and would like to know how this works.  What should my initial steps be in order to eventually achieve this feat?

I'm using React.js

Comment: Just pass full url of where you store it into href of an anchor tag.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I'm already doing that, but it's taking me to the hash that I was referring to.  I want my URL path to look something like `website/picture` and not `website/static/media/picture.e61334b7.pdf`

Comment: Shouldn't take you to a hash if url is absolute full path

Comment: @charlietfl I don't get what you mean, may you please elaborate?  Yes, my path looks like this: `import Picture from '../../Components/Picture/Picture';`.  Isn't this the absolute path?

Comment: So what's in that file? And no....unless it is returning a string url

Comment: @charlietfl apolgies!  I meant `import Picture from '../../Images/Picture.pdf';` . Isn't this the absolute path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179286/discussion-between-sp92-and-charlietfl).

Comment: No if that is a pdf file it has nothing to do with an external web url where you would put tht file

Comment: @charlietfl gotcha, what's an easy way to make an external web url?

Comment: Put it on server somewhere and get the url from wherever you put it. Open in browser and copy from address bar.

Comment: @charlietfl lol dude, that was my original question, how would I put it on server?

Comment: Also lots of free hosts like heroku